# Personal builds using Jenkins CI without SCM

Tags: jenkins

I'm curious if it is possible to use Jenkins CI without SCM in order to enable developers to run remote personal builds. I understand that the typical use case is to autotrigger a build as soon as changes are checked into SCM. I wonder if there are some people using Jenkins without SCM?

Basically, I envision the developer to upload his changed code to a directory on a server and then manually trigger a build (e.g. via a small web frontend) by entering the location of the uploaded code. This should be similar to performing a local build on a development machine. Preferably there should also be the option to omit some build steps or tests as they might not always be necessary for some changes.

Using a version control system like git this would probably be done by having developers check-in their experimental changes on separate branches before integrating with the master branch. Unfortunately, we do not have a version control system which provides easy ubiquitous branching. Therefore I'm asking for a solution where the developer uploads his local workspace directory to the Jenkins server in order to check if the build passes before commiting their changes to trunk.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you not already run the tests locally? Which steps *require* Jenkins?

Comment: Some tests cannot be run locally by every developer as they require special hardware which is only available in small quantity. Currently our developers wait until a central build server becomes available, then they remote login on that machine, run their build, and log off again. It would be nice to automatically queue such jobs and maybe even loadbalance jobs between available build servers. Finally, we also intend to setup Continuos Integration, and these personal builds should be performed under the same conditions as the CI build. Therefore I am wondering if Jenkins could do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way that I can think of to accomplish this is to create a parameterized Jenkins project with a file parameter and have your developers use that to upload a zip file that contains everything that will need to be tested, then have the build unzip, run the tests, and report the project status.

The steps of the project would essentially be:

- Check the `This project is parameterized` checkbox

  - Select `File Parameter` from the drop-down and fill out the required fields.
- Add another parameter (type dependent on how you choose to do it) that specifies tests to ignore.
- Wipe out the previous test build
- Use 7-zip or similar to unzip the uploaded file.
- Run all the tests and record build status.

Then when a user wants to kick off a build, they could just zip their directory up, go to the Jenkins project, click the `Build with parameters`, upload the file, and away it would go.  As long as concurrent builds are disabled (I believe the latest versions of Jenkins disable them by default, but I don't know for certain), I think that this would fill your needs, and have each build queue up for execution like what you want.

---

As an aside, and I know this is very much *not* your question, if you did use git, you could use something like [this process](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/dont-phunk-my-stable-branch-jenkins-pre-tested-commits-stop-breaking-stable-branches) to have Jenkins only push changes to the stable branch that have been successfully built.